# How to find the Taylor series of function $f(x)=\frac{a\left(1-x^2\right)+b\sqrt{x}\left(1+x\right)}{2\left(1-x\right)^2}$, at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

How to find the Taylor series of function $f(x)=\frac{a\left(1-x^2\right)+b\sqrt{x}\left(1+x\right)}{2\left(1-x\right)^2}$, at $x=0$. I know that the Taylor series of the functions:

$\frac{t}{1-t}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}t^{n+1}, \frac{t}{(1-t)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} nt^{n}$.

Comment: Due to the factor $\sqrt{x}$, this function is not analytic at $x=0$, so there is no Taylor series at $x=0$ (unless, of course, $b=0$). It is not even differentiable at $x=0$ when $b \neq 0$.

Comment: @Gary I think the function is analytic at $x=0$, since the $f(0)$ exists and is equal $$f(0)= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a\left(1-x^2\right)+b\sqrt{x}\left(1+x\right)}{2\left(1-x\right)^2}=\frac{a}{2}$$.

Comment: It means that it is continuous from the right at $x=0$. Analyticity is a much stronger requirement.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function For analyticity at $x=0$ a necessary requirement is that all the derivatives exist at $x=0$ (see Taylor's formula). For your function, already the first derivative does not exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to circumvent the problems underlined by @Gary and have an expansion using only integer powers, let $x=t^2$; using $t>0$, you need to work with
$$f(t)=\frac{a(1- t^4)+b \left(1+t^2\right) t}{2 \left(1-t^2\right)^2}=a\frac {(1+t^2)}{2(1-t^2) }+b\frac{ \left(1+t^2\right) t}{2 \left(1-t^2\right)^2}$$ which is not difficult using long division if you just need a few tems. If you do it and look at the patterns, you could conjecture that
$$f(t)=\frac a 2+\frac 14\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[(2 a \left(1+(-1)^n\right)+b \left(1-(-1)^n\right) n\Big]\,t^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\sqrt x=t$ leads to
$$\frac{a \left(1-t^4\right)+b t \left(t^2+1\right)}{2 \left(1-t^2\right)^2}=-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left[(b+2a)\frac{1}{1+t}-(b-2a)\frac{1}{1-t}+b\frac{1}{ (t-1)^2}-b\frac{1}{ (t+1)^2}\right]=$$
$$-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left[(b+2a)\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n t^n-(b-2a)\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } t^n+b\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (n+1) t^n-b\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n (n+1) t^n\right]=$$
$$-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(2 a \left((-1)^n+1\right)-b \left((-1)^n-1\right) n\right)t^n=$$
$$=-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(2 a \left((-1)^n+1\right)-b \left((-1)^n-1\right) n\right)x^{n/2}$$